# $H_0(S^2,A)$ where $A$ is a finite set of points

Tags: algebraic-topology

$H_0(S^2,A)$ where $A$ is a finite set of points.

Now, my first guess was that homology group would be $\mathbb{Z}$ because $S^2 - A$ has one path component. Unfortunately,  this is not the correct way to think about this. Can somebody offer some insight please?

The portion of the L.E.S. that is helpful is:

$0 \rightarrow H_1(S^2,A) \rightarrow H_0(A) \rightarrow H_0(S^2) \rightarrow H_0(S^2,A) \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Have you thought of taking a look at the long exact sequence of the pair ?

Comment: yes I did that. Unforuntately I am having a hard time getting the zero'th homology of this pair out of it, and I was hoping somebody could offer me some intuitive reason that it is true.

Comment: A slight variant of Max's suggestion: choose one of the points of $A$ to be the base point and have a look at the long exact sequence of reduced homology.

Comment: Can you try to see that $ H_0(A) \to H_0(S^2) $ is surjective if and only if $ A $ is nonempty ?

Comment: So then $\tilde{H_0(S^2)}$ is zero and so the zero'th reduced homlogy of $(S^2,A)$ must be zero because it is squished between two zero's? But that doesn't mean the unreduced homlogy still couldn't be $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Max yes indeed I do see that. I am always uneasy when trusting my intuition when working with long exact sequences, I just try to work with the exactness rather than thinking about what the induced maps actually are. I should try to change that.

Comment: Okay I got the answer, thank you. Does anyone have any intuitive reason that this should be true though?

Comment: Also the correct way to intuitively undersand relative homology is due to an isomorphism $H_i(X,A) \rightarrow H_i(X/A)$ if (X,A) is what is called a good pair. That is if A is closed and there exists open U containing A such that A is a strong deformation retract of U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let X be path connected and A any nonempty subspace of X.

The sequence

$$...\rightarrow H_{i}(A) \rightarrow H_{i}(X) \rightarrow H_{i}(X,A) \rightarrow H_{i-1}(A) \rightarrow ...$$ is then exact. Recall that $C_{i}(Y)$ is defined to be zero when $i<0$, then obviously $H_{i}(Y)$ is also zero so we get that $$...\rightarrow H_{0}(A) \rightarrow H_{0}(X) \rightarrow^{i_*} H_{0}(X,A) \rightarrow 0$$ is exact which means that $im (i_*)=H_{0}(X,A)$.

Let $c$ be a $0$-cycle, then $c$ is homologous to a $0$-cycle $z$ in $C_0(A)$ since $X$ is path-connected. Thus $i_*([c]) = (z+C_0(A))+im(\partial_1) = C_0(A)+im(\partial_1) = 0$

where we take $\partial_*$ to be the boundary operator in $C_*(X,A)$ and $[c]$ to be the homology class of $c$. Thus $i_* = 0$ and $H_0 (X,A)=im(i_*)=0$